# the$|.|_2$ norm properties

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have come across a lemma whose proof I do not quite get.

$$ $$
**Lemma.** Let $x_i \in \Omega^N$. Then, for any $\varphi \in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$,

$$|(D^- - \frac{d}{dx})\varphi(x_i)| \le \frac{1}{2}(x_{i+1}-x_{i-1})|\varphi|_2,$$

**Proof.** Using integration by parts to reduce the order of the differentiation in the integral, it is not hard to verify that

$$(D^- - \frac{d}{dx})\varphi(x_i) = \frac{1}{x_i-x_{i-1}}\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} (x_{i-1}-s)\varphi''(s)ds.$$
 It follows that that
$$|(D^- - \frac{d}{dx})\varphi(x_i)| \le \frac{|\varphi|_2}{x_i-x_{i-1}}\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} (s-x_{i-1})ds = \frac{1}{2}|\varphi|_2(x_i-x_{i-1}),$$

I could verify the first part that requires use of integration by parts as well as the right hand side of the inequality, however, I cannot figure out how to come up with the $|\varphi|_2$ norm. I would also appreciate suggestions on texts to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer involves some unexplained notation: $D^-$ and $|\varphi|_2$. But I think what happens here is the integral form of triangle inequality: $|\int f|\le \int|f|$, combined with  a pointwise inequality for the integrand. Indeed, 
$$|(x_{i-1}-s)\varphi''(s) | = (s-x_{i-1})|\varphi''(s)| \le  |\varphi|_2 (s-x_{i-1}) \tag1$$
assuming that $|\varphi|_2$ means the supremum of the second derivative (or the $C^2$ norm, which includes  the supremum of the second derivative).

Using (1), we obtain
$$ \left|\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} (x_{i-1}-s)\varphi''(s)\,ds\right| \le  
 \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} |\varphi|_2 (s-x_{i-1}) \,ds = |\varphi|_2\frac{(x_i-x_{i-1})^2}{2} \tag2$$
Divide by $(x_i-x_{i-1})$ and you are done.

Comment: @79365 much appreciated, the $D^-$ is representing the backward difference operator: $$ D^-\varphi(x_i)=\frac{\varphi(x_i)-\varphi(x_{i-1})}{x_i-x_{i-1}},$$

as for $|\varphi|_2$ I was not entirely certain what it stood for as it was not clearly defined by the authors of the text.